# Can I buy an RFID Baggage Card from Turkish Airlines with money instead of miles?

Tags: air-travel, turkish-airlines

> [The RFID Baggage Card](https://tr.shopandmiles.com/tk-collection-rfid-bagaj-kart%C4%B1) helps to solve any problems you might experience with your baggage while traveling and enables you to track the movement of your baggage at certain points as well.
>   Additionally, you will be informed with an SMS when your baggage arrives at the baggage delivery area after your flight. Therefore, you will not have to wait until your baggage arrives, and you will be able to take care of your needs during this period.

I cant seem to find the option of buying with with anything but miles. Any idea if it's possible to purchase it from the airport?

[image]

Comment: Are you a Turkish Airlines Miles & Smiles member?

Comment: @Giorgio no, How do I become one?

Comment: Start with [TA Miles & Smiles](https://www.turkishairlines.com/tr-tr/miles-and-smiles/); apparently the RFID card is attached to the membership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got my answer from Twitter

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The data on the [Turkish Airlines RFID Baggage Card](https://tr.shopandmiles.com/tk-collection-rfid-bagaj-kart%C4%B1) is coordinated with membership in its [Miles & Smiles](https://www.turkishairlines.com/tr-tr/miles-and-smiles/), so you would have to participate in that program (and, hence, use mileage to obtain the card):

> As the RFID Baggage Card works integrated with your Miles & Smiles membership, no personal information is included on the card. You will be contacted via your contact information in your Miles & Smiles account.